# GAE more than 3 attributes to filter?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Hie

I am using GAE jdoql and wrote query like:

```
    Query query = pm.newQuery(BloodDonor.class);  
        query.setFilter(" state == :stateName && district == :distName &&" +
                " city == :cityName && bloodGroup == :blood");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<BloodDonor> donors = (List<BloodDonor>) query.execute(state.toLowerCase(), district.toLowerCase(),
                city.toLowerCase(), bloodGroup.toLowerCase());
```

This doesnt work as execute method does not support more than 3 parameters. So how to pass more than 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok figured our myself. The right method is to use query.executeWithArray in this case

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html) you can add multiple filters by calling the `addFilter` method multiple times:

```
Query query = pm.newQuery("BloodDonor");  
query.addFilter("state", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, state.toLowerCase());
query.addFilter("district", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, city.toLowerCase());
query.addFilter("bloodGroup", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, bloodGroup.toLowerCase());

PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

for (Entity result : pq.asIterable()) {
   // Do stuff
}
```